# Desktop Application Development with Javascript, Python / Ruby

Tags: javascript, python, ruby, desktop-application

Besides using Appcelerator's Titanium Desktop, are there other approaches to integrating Javascript and Ruby/Python into cross-platform desktop applications?  Just trying to get a sense of the landscape here.  From searching the web, it seems Titanium may be leading the charge in terms of this type of integration.  I wasn't able to find references that suggest you can do something similar in Adobe AIR.

I am interested in building desktop applications that exploit Protovis and possibly other Javascript interactive vis packages for the UI.  At the end of the day, I can go the web app route if need be, but being able to develop desktop apps is helpful.

Would appreciate your perspective on this...

Chris

Answer (score 2):

There is [Pyjamas Desktop](http://pyjd.org/), but might be a bit out of date.

Comment: Why out of date? Development seems to be quite active.

Comment: @nikow: Well, the last packaged download is from 2008 or so.

Comment: Is that maybe because it is now part of the Pyjamas main distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You can also script Swing or SWT with JRuby, either directly, or via one of the numerous [frameworks](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/GUIFrameworks).
You might manage to integrate protovis via a webkit or gecko (like [redcar does](http://github.com/danlucraft/redcar)) embedding, or a java html renderer, there are some. Or just use a java viz kit.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback clyfe.